# Assigning a Iron Python list to .NET array

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a list comprehension operating on elements of an .NET array like

```
obj.arr = [f(x) for x in obj.arr]
```

However the assignment back to obj.arr fails.

Is it possible to convert a list to a .NET array in IronPython?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
obj.arr = Array[T]([f(x) for x in obj.arr])
```

replacing `T` with type of array elements.

Alternatively:

```
obj.arr = tuple([f(x) for x in obj.arr])
```

Comment: I tried the tuple(list) option since I didn't want to specify T and it works. Never knew that tuples can be assigned to arrays like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays have to be typed as far as I know.  This works for me:

```
num_list = [n for n in range(10)]

from System import Array
num_arr = Array[int](num_list)
```

Similarly for strings and other types.