# calling CLR method with variable arguments from IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython

I am using Iron Python as an added 'for free' tool to test the an API that wrapps comms to some custom hardware so the non-development team can play with the hardware via python.

However I can't work out how to get .NET `void func(params object[] args)` to map to Python `def (*args)`.

Here is some code to explain.

I have a type that allows injecting a logging callback to format and deal with messages is follows the signature of Console.WriteLine and Debug.WriteLine.

```
public class Engine
{
    Action<string, object[]> _logger;
    public void Run()
    {
        Log("Hello '{0}'", "world");
    }
    public void SetLog(Action<string, object[]> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    void Log(string msg, params object[] args)
    {
        _logger(msg, args);
    }
}
```

in my IronPython code

```
import clr
from System import *
from System.IO import Path
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(Path.GetFullPath(r"MyAssembly.dll"))
from MyNamespace import *

def logger(msg, *args):
    print( String.Format(msg, args))
    print( String.Format(msg, list(args)))
    print( String.Format(msg, [args]))
    a=[]
    for i in args:
        a.append(i)
    print( String.Format(msg, a) )

e = Engine()
e.SetLog(logger)
e.Run()
```

output

```
Hello '('world',)'
Hello 'IronPython.Runtime.List'
Hello 'IronPython.Runtime.List'
Hello 'IronPython.Runtime.List'
```

I would like

```
Hello 'world'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning a Iron Python list to .NET array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107789/assigning-a-iron-python-list-to-net-array)

Comment: If it is a duplicate of that post then either I don't understand my own question or I don't understand theirs (or both :-)

Comment: I think the question referenced by @HansPassant is not a hard duplicate but hints at one of the possible solutions (see my answer and the conversion to `Array[object]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) handles your iron python objects (tuple for your first output case, lists for the last three) as single objects and is not aware that you would like the python collection to be used as `params object[]` you are getting the unexpected output. The single python object/tuple is implicitly created when `def logger` is invoked.

Depending on your actual use-case/style you can solve this in different ways.

The most python-y way would be expanding the arguments at their call site like Jeff explains in his answer:

```
def logger(msg, *args):
    print( String.Format(msg, *args) )
```

If you call `logger` only as from CLR as implementation of `Action<string, object[]>` you could just have `args` be a single (not variable) argument of type `object[]` like

```
def logger(msg, args):
    print( String.Format(msg, args) )
```

If you would like to call `logger` from python with variable arguments as well (and you don't mind the back and forth conversion) you could do

```
def logger(msg, *args):
    print( String.Format(msg, Array[object](args)) )
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the Array[object](args) solution. The fact that I can use python at all is a bonus, so this cast which would be hidden away from most users is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, this should work:

```
def logger(msg, *args):
    print(String.Format(msg, *args))
```

Comment: Expanding the var args at call cite seems to be more elegant! I will check/verify and delete my answer if that works out for all cases.